# angular and firebase: Cannot find namespace 'firebase'

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, ionic-framework, angularfire2

I am getting the below error while working with angular and firebase:

> Typescript Error
>
> Cannot find namespace 'firebase'.

C:/Users/DELL/Desktop/connect/withfire/node_modules/angularfire2/auth/auth.d.ts

```
 app: FirebaseApp; 
 readonly auth: firebase.auth.Auth; 
 readonly authState: Observable<firebase.User | null>;
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to downgrade firebase version.
Try this: `$ npm install -s firebase@4.8.0`

Answer (score 4):

4.8.1 was a refactor of the typings and you now pull your imports from `@firebase:`

```
import { FirebaseApp } from '@firebase/app-types';
import { FirebaseAuth } from '@firebase/auth-types';
import { FirebaseDatabase } from '@firebase/database-types';
import { FirebaseMessaging } from '@firebase/messaging-types';
import { FirebaseStorage } from '@firebase/storage-types';
import { FirebaseFirestore } from '@firebase/firestore-types';
```

import what ever module you need

Answer (score 2):

npm install firebase@4.8.0 --save-dev

Answer (score 1):

**Update: 29-01-2018**

This worked for me

```
  "angularfire2": "5.0.0-rc.6",
  "firebase": "4.8.2",
```

***Note:*** Don't forget to delete `node_modules` folder and `npm i`.

Comment: You just saved my life. Thank-you kind sir!

Comment: Glad to hear that it helped :) @Jared